# Log Inverse Gamma Distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Can any one help me to know the formula for mean and variance of log inverse gamma distribution. Thanks

Comment: Since the term log-<distribution name> is unfortunately used in two opposite senses, can you be precise - do you mean the distribution of the log of an inverse gamma random variable or do you mean the distribution of a variable which if you took its log would be inverse gamma?

Comment: Can you help us out by specifying the functional form of the pdf you are working with ..

Comment: i mean the log of an inverse random variable, the pdf is like this. f(x)=beta^alpha/gamma(alpha) exp{-alpha*x-beta*exp(-x)}.

Comment: Is this for some class?

Comment: i did not get by word (class?)

Comment: I mean: Is this a question arising from study, as might be found in a textbook, exercise, assignment, past exam, etc?

Comment: Incidentally, the log of an inverse gamma is the negative of the log of a gamma. This problem yields to simple methods. [The methods described here might be of some help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Logarithmic_expectation).

Comment: I have no idea either this question is available in any text. I saw the log transformation of gamma random varaible as log gamma distribution, and mean and variance of log gamma distribution as log(beta)+digammafunction(alpha) and trigammafunction(alpha). I tried to find the log transformation of inverse gamma random variable and i find it as log inverse gamma distribution, now i dont know what is the mean and variance of log inverse gamma distribution. Please help me to find this. thanks.

Comment: So this is self-study?

Comment: yes, may be i will use it in my research in future. The link you send it shows that the mean of log inverse gamma distribution will be log(beta)-digammafunction(alpha) and variance remain the same. am i right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> mean and variance of log gamma distribution as log(beta)+digammafunction(alpha) and trigammafunction(alpha).

The distribution of the log of an inverse gamma random variable is the distribution of -log of a gamma r.v. as I explained in comments.

As such:

i) if you have the density  of the log of a gamma, simply replace $x$ by $-x$,

ii) since $E(-X)=-E(X)$, you simply negate the expectation of the log-gamma, and

iii) since $Var(-X)=Var(X)$, you have the same variance as the log-gamma.

So there's nothing to do; you already solved it in doing the log of a Gamma r.v.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clearance.... Indeed i was confuse here now i am clear. Thanks alot.